# How to implement stack and queue in java?

Tags: java, stack

How to implement stack and queue in java ?

Comment: You have predefined classes in Java for Stack and Queue in java.util.

Answer (score 3):

There are predefined classes in Java for these data structures: [java.util.Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) and [java.util.Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) (choose one of the implementations for `Queue`).